# AWS Consolidated Billing and multiple accounts in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I will be hosting infrastructure for several different clients. Complete, total, 100% separation of client's AWS infrastructure is necessary (leagal etc). So I need some advice on how best to structure my accounts.

I will have a master account with MFA. It will not actually ever spin-up and infrastructure. It is merely to be a top-level billing account. Then each client will have their own separate AWS account. With I guess a separate root login and separate MFA. Each client account will be linked to the Master account for consolidated billing. This is neat because if they move their business else where then we just give them the IAM details for the account and strike it off from Master and we are done.

What I am not sure of is that to set up a brand new AWS account you need a unique email account. We don't want the client to ever have to first setup the account so do we need to have a whole bunch of email aliases to use on our company domain (client@mydomain.com, client2@mydomain.com etc) and then use them to set up new AWS accounts? Is there a better way than this? It could get pretty clunky to have to have a new email alias every time a new client joins.

Second, will we need a box full of MFA devices - one for each account, or will the same device work for all accounts?

Any pointers gratefully received. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a Gmail address like example@gmail.com, then you can register AWS accounts using email addresses like:

```
example+CUSTOMER1@gmail.com
example+CUSTOMER2@gmail.com
example+CUSTOMER3@gmail.com
```

and all the emails will go to your same gmail account. You could auto forward from gmail to another address.

This also works for Google Apps email addresses, if you are using that to host your company email.

Instead of physical MFA devices, you can use the Google Authenticator app on an Android or iPhone with one entry for each customer AWS account.

Answer (score 1):

You mention consolidated billing in your question title, but not in your question.

Beware the following re. consolidated billing:

If you purchase reserved instances for one client, the benefit of that will be shared with all your clients, so your costs will be out of sync.

If you plan to re-charge your clients, and you want to use reserved instances, don't use consolidated billing.

As for you question:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/12096?hl=en

Most email platforms support some form of aliasing.

You may also be interested in

http://www.nightbluefruit.com/blog/2014/02/command-line-tool-for-checking-status-of-instances-in-amazon-ec2/

Comment: thanks, could you please explain a bit more about why reserved instances are shared across accounts?

Comment: Reserved instances are actually accounting devices rather than actual instances in the EC2 cloud. They are basically a discount that Amazon applies to your account. When you have a consolidated bill, the discount is applies based on the total of resources used. I think their logic is that if you have unused reserved instances (ie discounts) its better to apply them somewhere rather than just let them go. However, if one of your clients has paid the upfront charge for the instance, it doesn't make sense for another client to be getting the benefit.

Comment: Also, its not just a question of "unused" reserved instances. The benefit of reserved instances is attributed based on usage in the individual accounts. Its explained here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/consolidatedbilling.html#consolidatedbilling-ec2, but the logic is lost on me.

Comment: You can try https://totalcloud.io/ to manage RI costs too. I use it since it is free to me as my AWS spent is below $5,000.